# How to use simple permutational regression (lmp; aovp) line in scatter plot (ggplot)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, permutation, regression

I would like to ask how to use simple permutational regression line (lmp, aovp) in scatter plot (ggplot) instead of non-permutational regression line (lm).

Here is my code:

```
colorpal <- brewer.pal(10, "Paired")
x = density_2$Rych_D
y = density_2$PK_DC
group = density_2$Group
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y,group=factor(group))
df_ell = data.frame()
for(g in levels(df$group)){df_ell = rbind(df_ell,cbind(as.data.frame(with(df[df$group==g,],ellipse(cor(x,y),scale=c(sd(x),sd(y)),centre=c(mean(x),mean(y))))),group=g))}
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y,colour=group)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) + geom_path(data=df_ell, aes(x=x, y=y,colour=group))+scale_colour_manual(values=colorpal)+theme_classic()
```

I tried to use function lmp instead of lm in geom_smooth(method=) but I the following error was occurred: *Error in qr.Q(z$qr, complete = TRUE) : argument is not a QR decomposition* and the regression lines disappeared from the plot.

Comment: Can you please provide the data?

Comment: If at all possible, post the output of `dput(density_2)` in your question. If it's too long, then perhaps upload it somewhere and provide a link.

Comment: Here is the link for dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5bgcas1omqwlxf/density_2.txt?dl=0